# Как сделать кнопку поиск и выпадающие меню одновременно

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Я сделал что-то вроде этого, но мне нужно чтобы вся кнопка была поиском а не какая-то часть. Что я хочу сделать будет изображено на картинке.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.body {
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

.btn-space {
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.save_button {
    min-width: 80px;
    max-width: 80px;
}
div.btn-group.btn-lgg {
    margin: -5;
    padding: -5;
}
.btn-lg {
    width: 362px;
    position: relative;
}
.btn-lgg {
    width: 243px;
    height: 46px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Block</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
   <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <!-- Optional theme -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="row" style = "margin-left:-10px; margin-top:200px;margin:display;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type ="button" class="btn btn-light btn-lg"data-toggle="dropdown">
        <form class="form-search">
          <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query">
          <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i> 
        </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
            <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class = "divider"></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </form>
      </div><!--
   --><div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class ="btn btn-light btn-lgg"data-toggle="dropdown">
          <i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i>Primary
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
          <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class = "divider"></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--
   --><div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class ="btn btn-light btn-lgg"data-toggle="dropdown">Test 3</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
          <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class = "divider"></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--
   --><div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class ="btn btn-light btn-lgg"data-toggle="dropdown">Test 3</button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
          <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
          <li class = "divider"></li>
          <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: мб сделать input кнопокой?

Comment: Можете привести пример?

Answer (score 0):

input c drop-down action:

```css
body{
  padding: 10px;
}
input {
  border: 5px solid silver;
  background-color: silver;
  color: #fff !important;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Block</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="struct.css" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <!-- Optional theme -->
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <form class="form-search">
         <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" data-toggle="dropdown">
         <ul class="dropdown-menu" role = "menu">
            <li><a href = "#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li class = "divider"></li>
            <li><a href = "#">Separated link</a></li>
         </ul>
         <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>   
       </form>
      </div>

      <!-- jQuery -->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```